# Changing RootViewController type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

Ok, I have been following along with a tutorial and I have completed that, all works fine. However the initial view that loads is a UITableViewController and I would like a UIViewController.

Here is the code for that:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    
    return true
}
```

I have tried editing this line:

```
UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

to:

```
window?.rootViewController = UIViewController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

But then I am given this error:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rootViewController:', expected 'coder:')

It then asks me to 'Fix-it' so I do, which changes the line to:

```
window?.rootViewController = UIViewController(coder: ViewController())
```

But then this now throws the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'

I have also tried:

```
window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
```

but with that, the simulator goes black.

## Clarify Question:

How do I get the first View that loads in my app to be of type UIViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subclass `UIViewController` and make your own version to check it works, but what you're doing originally is fine

```
let myViewController = SomeViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Then in `SomeViewController` `viewDidLoad` set `view.backgroundColor = .red`

If you want to remove the navigation bar you can set it to hidden

```
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true
```

alternatively...

```
let myViewController = SomeViewController()
window?.rootViewController = myViewController
```

Will also work... though you should be looking to keep the navigation controller in general.. it usually makes presenting view controllers a lot easier in the future...

The reason your simulator goes black is because it worked... you're showing an empty `UIViewController`... You must make your own `UIViewController` subclass and add stuff to it.

Your View Controller subclass should look like this

```
//
//  SomeViewController.swift
//  SomeProject
//
//  Created by Magoo on 17/10/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Magoo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red

        let label = UILabel(frame:view.bounds)
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.text = "Hello world"

        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

The result should be a red screen with 'Hello world' written in the centre.

Comment: Sorry, slightly new. What do you mean: 'You must make your own UIViewController subclass and add stuff to it.' could you explain? I have already created a new file of type UIViewController which has 'class SomeViewController: UIViewController {'

Comment: In XCode, go to File -> New -> File and choose Swift File. Then Call it SomeViewController.swift ... that file will then be available to you in your project... and you can edit it however you'd like.

Comment: Basically everything that you want to show on the screen in this case needs to be in `SomeViewController` that's the view that's displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your awesome and detailed explanation. Much Appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a label too to better explain my point